# Joomla : Want to build custom form with my own back hand code

Tags: joomla

I just want to create custom html with good css form with my own php as backhand code and javascript for validation.. Is there any extension for this?
I have seen few extensions but none of them allows me to add my own php backhand code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use Joomla's framework, then you may as well build the form outside of joomla and insert it into the article via an iframe (you may need to change the editor's permissions to allow you to do this).

It is worth looking into using the framework properly, however, as it does have easy-to-use mail classes and actually makes things easier when you get your head around it.

(Though to answer your actual question - this module appears to allow you to add raw php http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/3668 )

Comment: Jumi also looks like what you may have been looking for... http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/1023